# How to enable sRGB Framebuffer on GvrView Android surface?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, google-cardboard, google-vr

Is anyone aware of a way to enable sRGB on Google VR SDK's `GvrView` ?

For classic `GLSurfaceView`, I use `setEGLWindowSurfaceFactory`, which works nice - see below.

In my understanding, this surface factory is not exposed by `GvrView`, is there any workaround or alternative way ? through NDK api ?

I could not find anything in official docs.

```
view.setEGLWindowSurfaceFactory(mWindow_sRGB_SurfaceFactory);

private final EGLWindowSurfaceFactory mWindow_sRGB_SurfaceFactory = new EGLWindowSurfaceFactory() {

        public EGLSurface createWindowSurface(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
                                              EGLConfig config, Object nativeWindow) {
            EGLSurface result = null;
            final int EGL_GL_COLORSPACE_KHR = 0x309D;
            final int EGL_GL_COLORSPACE_SRGB_KHR = 0x3089;
            final int[] surfaceAttribs = {
                    EGL_GL_COLORSPACE_KHR, EGL_GL_COLORSPACE_SRGB_KHR,
                    EGL10.EGL_NONE
            };

            result = egl.eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, nativeWindow, surfaceAttribs);
            ...
        }
```